# Does this method count as planting?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In **Animal Crossing: New Leaf**, you can get the *Backyard Gardener* badge by planting **100** plants. There are two ways to drop a plant(more specifically a flower) to the ground: by dragging the flower icon to the floor, and by touching the flower icon and selecting *plant*. Does the first method count as planting, or do I need to manually press *plant*  in the inventory? Because to me, that's basically "tossing" the plant to the ground.

Comment: If the game mechanic is the same for both then i'm 99% sure both will count. If dragging and dropping just drops the item instead of planting it in soil then obviously just dropping it does not count. Other then that, why not test it out with a cheat, 100 does not seem many.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to an [Animal Crossing: New Leaf wiki](http://acwiki3ds.wikispaces.com/Badges), the *Backyard Gardener* badge can only be obtained through planting flower seeds; replanting doesn't count:

> Planting flowers taken from the Tropical Island, Villages you have visited and replanting flowers do not count towards your total needed.

(I assume you meant replanting flowers, since drag-and-drop for seeds just drops the packet onto the ground.)

Comment: At first I thought you were mistaken but then after thinking I realized you were correct. If you have a flower in your inventory it is because you had picked it up from the ground. You can't have a flower in your inventory that was not previously planted.

Answer (score 5):

in Wild World(DS) when you drag it off screen it plants the flower (signified by sound and it popping out of the ground). If the flower comes out of the ground when you drag it, its planted. if not. its dropped and doesnt count towards the plant flower mission